# How to run Powershell on sites when you have IP

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I'm new to creating an external site, but between my client's IT guy and me, we managed to create and external site and we can access it by entering the ip address.

For example if `ip=123.45.67.8` the URL is then `http://123.45.67.8/External`

I want to run powershell scripts on this site - but get error:

> Get-SPSite:  Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or URL
>   http://123.45.67.8/External

So I assume I must change the ip rather to something else.  Please guide me on how to do that?  Or can I use the IP address in my Powershell commands, but then what cause the error?

Comment: Are you running the script on the server itself or on another computer?

Comment: I'm running it on the server itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure if you can get it by IP or not? But one thing i am thinking you can access the site collection by ID.

```
Get-Spsite | Select URL, ID
```

This will give you the ID of the site collection, then you can run the following to get the site collection

```
Get-SPSite fr98we20-0dcd-560f-b44f-791fef2d034d4
```